# Generating SQL script from MySQL database table

Tags: mysql

Is there any application that will read a MySQL database table and generate a SQL script of INSERT statements (so that I can copy tables from one db to another db)? OR how can I transfer content from db1.table1 to db2.table2 where table1 and table2 is same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mysqldump [options] db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

Will generate the script file including the create and inserts necessary for the tables selected.  To import the dump you can simply do:

```
mysql -u <user> -p dbname < mys.dmp
```

Comment: Could you let me know how can I specify DB host and port?

Comment: mysql (or mysqldump) -h <host> -P <port>
Thanks for the point and answer!

Comment: It worked. Thank you. The only point I would like to add is this: mysqldump use only one INSERT statement while creating the script. Using --skip-opt will create each INSERT statement separately.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html). You can specify the `--nodata` option to export the schema only.

Comment: mysqldump -u user -p database_name --no-data > output_file.sql